# How can i set scale for each layer symbol?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-10.0

I'd like to use reference scale : 1:10000000 for layer a and 1:2000000 for layer b to set scale of labels and symbologies. one method is [Working with data frame reference scales](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00660000043v000000)

but this method works for all of layers in data frame . i want to use scales separately.
How can i set scales for each layer? or any method to set size of symbology and labels?